# How to access a variable from another function

Tags: python, splinter

I want to get the variable `browser` from `self.login()` function and use it in the `test_pages` function. `browser=?` is where I want to use the variable.
How do I do that?

```
    def test_pages(self, browser=?):
        self.login()
        pages = ["page1", "page2", "page3"]
        for page in pages:
            browser.visit(f"{self.base_url}/test/{page}")
            if browser.is_text_present('Log Out'):
                print("navigate_" + page + " Pass")
            else:
                print("navigate_" + page + " Fail")

    def login(self):
        browser = Browser('chrome')
        browser.visit(f"{self.base_url}/login")
        browser.fill('email', self.get_user_email())
        browser.fill('password', self.get_user_password())
        # Find and click the 'search' button
        button = browser.find_by_value("Sign In")
        # Interact with elements
        button.click()
        return browser
```

Comment: `self.login()` returns browser, so assign the return value to a variable `browser` in the `test_pages` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the value returned by `self.login()` in `test_pages()` as follows:

`browser = self.login()`